How to change Sender name in Outlook Desktop in Microsoft 365 Family subscription
I'm using Outlook 365 on my Windows PC, which is connected to my Microsoft 365 Family subscription.  I am wanting the Sender on emails I send to show with my full name, eg "Mida Valo" instead of first name plus initial of last name, eg "Mida V"
I updated my Microsoft account to use my full name, and after doing that I restarted my PC and both Windows and Outlook show me as logged in with my full name.
But here's the issue - when I send an email from the Outlook Desktop app, the sender name still shows up as "Mida V".
What I've tried:

Emails sent from Outlook Web use my correct full name as set in my Microsoft account.
In Outlook Desktop I can't find the option to update the "Your Name" field, which is suggested in most online results.  Those solutions say if it shows as "Microsoft Exchange" that I need to contact my administrator (I guess I'm the administrator as it's a Personal subscription!)
My account is listed as an Exchange account, but since I’m using a Microsoft 365 Family subscription (not a business/Exchange account), I don’t have access to the usual "Exchange Settings" options suggested in various solutions.  At least, I couldn't find them anywhere in my account.
I tried removing and re-adding the account in Outlook Desktop, but I ran into this error:
"The primary account cannot be removed unless it is the only account in the profile. You must remove all other Exchange accounts before removing the primary account."
However, I have 4 accounts in that profile, and I don’t use Outlook profiles actively — just the default one.

How can I update the sender name in the Outlook Desktop app to match the full name set in my Microsoft Account? I can’t seem to find the right settings, and removing/re-adding the account isn’t straightforward due to the profile issue.
(Note that this is the Outlook installed with Office, not the new one that replaces Mail)
